# How to enable Git terminal begin with home directory in Windows?

Tags: windows, git, github

Git-bash is starting up from the directory where the Git-bash application is installed i.e at `"C:/Program Files/Git"` and it is displaying these prompts right after I launch Git-bash.exe:

`bash: /c/Users/Kedar/git-prompt.sh: No such file or directory`

This is so insane because I definitely have placed git-prompt.sh file in that path
It is not starting from the home directory as it was expected i.e. `Kedar ~ $`
Yes, I can reach this directory but after I type this command - `Kedar / $ cd ~/`

So, my query is to how to enable Git terminal to start up with home directory i.e. `Kedar ~ $` and not `Kedar / $` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Windows, do this

- Right click on the Windows shortcut that you use to launch git bash terminal i.e git-bash.exe, and click Properties.
- Go to tab named Shortcut
- Change the value of Start in: label to your desired workspace path i.e. `C:\Users\Kedar` maybe in your case

Then you should run the application as administrator!

Answer (score 2):

Also assuming you use Windows, there are two ways:

1. Simple way: As [Divyanshu Kushwaha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42663263/7598462) explained, open the Properties of the shrotcut you use to launch and just place `--cd-to-home` behind the target path that points to your `git-bash.exe` file, like this: `"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --cd-to-home`.
2. Flexible way: You can configure the bash command line via the `.bashrc` file in your home folder. If the file does not exist, you can create it and then add something like this:

   ```
   MoveToHome() { cd /c/<any path you want>; }
   MoveToHome
   ```

   This lets you define any path you want to be in on startup, by defining a MoveToHome function and calling it right on startup.